# solid border and transparent background in ie8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

i tried everything to achieve this and it works in every browser (also ie7) except ie8!
what am i doing wrong? i just want a transparent background-color and a solid border.

```
.container{
    background:#ffcc00;
    background:transparent\9;
    background:rgba(255, 204, 0,0.5);
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(GradientType=0,startColorstr='#FFFFFF', endColorstr='#003366')"; /* IE8 */
    border: 1px solid #ffcc00;
    border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
    zoom:1;
}
```

Comment: I have never seen something like this `transparent\9`

Comment: its a hack. \9 makes this css definition only visible for ie8

Comment: the filter only definition doesnt work either

Comment: did you try this one? http://kimili.com/journal/rgba-hsla-css-generator-for-internet-explorer/

Comment: wow thanks. now it works in ie8 but not in ie7 :D but better this way round thank you very much

Comment: https://web.archive.org/web/20130829031726/kimili.com/journal/rgba-hsla-css-generator-for-internet-explorer/